# Use Reflection.Emit to override a method

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I am working on a tool using `System.Reflection.Emit` to generate proxy types for an abstract base class. The final requirement for now is to be able to override virtual/abstract methods by supplying a `Func`, and allowing the proxy to call that `Func` retaining the object context of the original call. For example, given a simple type like:

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int NameLen() => 42;
}
```

I'd want to be able to supply a `Func<A, int>` to override `NameLen`. I'm able to generate the base proxy easily enough, but I can't quite make the override work. Here is a minimal example, proxying the class above:

```
static Type GetProxyFor(Type type, Func<A, int> oride, string methodName)
{
    // basic type setup
    var assmName = new AssemblyName("AproxyAssm");
    var assmBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var moduleBuilder = assmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assmName.Name);
    var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("AProxy", TypeAttributes.Public, type);

    // create the override method
    var mInfo = typeBuilder.BaseType.GetMethod(methodName);
    var mBody = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(mInfo.Name,
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.ReuseSlot | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
        mInfo.ReturnType, null);

    // call the Func 
    var ilGen = mBody.GetILGenerator();
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, oride.Target.GetType().GetFields()[0]); // ???
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0); // load method obj context as func arg 1
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, oride.Method);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo();
    var rettype = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    return rettype;
}
```

The generated IL appears to be correct, as I'm not getting any JIT errors or the old favorite `CLR detected an invalid program`, and the proxy class works otherwise, even for more complex examples. As long, that is, as I don't call the overridden method. What I do get when I call the method is `System.FieldAccessException : Attempt by method 'AProxy.NameLen()' to access field 'EmitTests.OverrideTests+<>c.<>9' failed. ' failed.`

A unit test combining everything above:

```
[Fact]
public void CanEmitOverrideMethod()
{
    Func<A, int> f = (t) => t.Name.Length;

    var t = GetProxyFor(typeof(A), f, "NameLen");

    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<A>(obj);
    ((A)obj).Name = "Foo";

    Assert.Equal(3, ((A)obj).NameLen());
}
```

---

Updated with slightly more concise example. Also, here is the output from ILSpy, when examining the generated `<>c` class:

```
// EmitTests.OverrideTests.<>c
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[Serializable]
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

    public static Func<A, int> <>9__1_0;

    internal int <CanEmitOverrideMethod>b__1_0(A t)
    {
        return t.Name.Length;
    }
}
```

To me this all looks right, and I'm a little stumped where to go next.

Comment: *"func is called like a static"* - I think that's the mistake. The lambda is an instance method on the nested `<>c` class, so `ldnull` is wrong there. The compiler creates a static field that keeps a single instance of the class (because it doesn't capture anything). You need to load that instance (`oride.Target`) instead of null for the first parameter. At least that's my guess at a glance. I haven't tried it.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but I'm not actually grokking how to load the `oride.Target` there. Any hints?

Comment: My guess would be `oride.Target.GetType().GetFields().First()` to get the static field's `FieldInfo` and then use the `ldsfld` instruction. That assumes a single lambda in the method so "first" and "only" are equivalent. It also assumes that the delegate is provided as a lambda. If it's not, it won't work. Keep in mind that this is a compiler implementation detail so it could change without notice and break your implementation.

Comment: No dice, see update above

Comment: You missed the '`s`' ... Use `OpCodes.Ldsfld` because it's a static field.

Comment: Derp. Ok, now a `FieldAccessException`.

Comment: I'd still say that's progress. Keep at it. Load the unit test assembly in ILSpy and examine what's generated for the lambda and see if that leads you to any revelations.

Comment: I agree, but I'm going to have to leave this till tomorrow at least. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't feel nearly as clever or interesting as what I was aiming for with the `Emit` override, but it a) works and b) is probably more maintainable. When creating the proxy types, I register the func with a static dictionary, and then do a lookup at runtime. Some quick and dirty benchmarking suggests the lookup is basically free; calling an instance with no registered func is just as fast as calling a regular method over 1 million repetitions. With a func registered there is a tiny bit of overhead, but it only adds up to a fraction of a second over the same 1m reps. The overhead appears to be in the actual invoking of the Func, which would presumably also exist in the Emit() method above.

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int NameLen()
    {
        var t = this.GetType();
        if (funcs.ContainsKey(t))
        {
            return funcs[t](this);
        }
        else
        {
            return 42;
        }
    }

    public static Dictionary<Type, Func<A, int>> funcs = new Dictionary<Type, Func<A, int>>();
}
```

And the proxy generator:

```
static Type GetProxyFor<T>(Func<A, int> oride) where T : A
{
    // basic type setup
    var assmName = new AssemblyName("AproxyAssm");
    var assmBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var moduleBuilder = assmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(assmName.Name);
    var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("AProxy", TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(T));

    typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo();
    var rettype = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    if (oride != null)
    {
        A.funcs.Add(rettype, oride);
    }

    return rettype;
}
```